Why does the cross sectional area of the air going into the inlet of a turbo fan changes during take off and cruise?
This is the first time I see this and I'm trying to make sense of it, I was reading these slides:
https://slideplayer.com/slide/13267627/
I'm having trouble understanding why the area of the streamtube of air going into the inlet is much larger than the inlet during take off than during cruise. Also why the mass flow rate and thrust is much bigger during take of than in cruise?
I'm trying to relate it to the pressure in the ground being much bigger in the ground than at cruise altitude, but that makes it even more confusing because the fan creates lower pressure zone to suck in air right?, but lower pressure is more related to higher gas volume, so I'm completely lost.



why [is] the area of the streamtube of air going into the inlet [] much larger than the inlet during take off than during cruise?

Because at low speed the engine has to suck in air while at high speed the air is pushed into it. So much actually that only the core of the streamtube can be ingested and the rest spills over the intake lips.

why [is] the mass flow rate and thrust [] much bigger during take of than in cruise?

Because cruise happens in much less dense air. A cubic meter of air on the ground weighs roughly three times as much as a cubic meter at altitude.

"Because cruise happens in much denser air"...you mean "less dense air", right?

@Gabe Oh boy, it was late when I wrote this ... of course you are right.
